# How to push data into influxdb from python and also node.js simultaneously

Tags: python, node.js, influxdb

I am working with influxdb to push the data from python and also node.js. I am able to push the data using separate database for each language. Data is not inserting when both the language using same database.

Any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I did't get any error.I could able to push in influxdb simultaneous.but value is not listing when two different source pushing simultaneously